# java neo4j cypher query to match node

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I'm pretty sure I should see the error I'm making myself. And I'm also sure, I should know how to construct a decent cypher query within java, but I simply can't. It's late and I've been banging my head on this since the last 4 hours. So, I'm giving up.

I have a relatively simply cypher query I want to execute against an open transaction endpoint

```
 http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/[# number]
```

So I figured, I do it just the way I do it when creating a node, but simply match instead of create:

```
  {"statements": [ {"statement": "MATCH (p:POST {properties}) RETURN p", "parameters": {"properties":{"sn_id": "TW", "id": "536627264453353472"}} } ] }
```

But the server tells me, I cannot use parameter maps in a match like that:

```
  TRACE Neo4JPersistence - sending cypher {"statements": [ {"statement": "MATCH (p:POST {properties}) RETURN p", "parameters": {"properties":{"sn_id": "TW", "id": "536627264453353472"}} } ] } to endpoint http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/75
  TRACE Neo4JPersistence - GET to http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/75 returned status code 200, returned data: {"commit":"http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/75/commit","results":[],"transaction":{"expires":"Sun, 23 Nov 2014 21:09:05 +0000"},"errors":[{"code":"Neo.ClientError.Statement.InvalidSyntax","message":"Parameter maps cannot be used in MATCH patterns (use a literal map instead, eg. \"{id: {param}.id}\") (line 1, column 15)\n\"MATCH (p:POST {properties}) RETURN p\"\n               ^"}]}
  ERROR Neo4JPersistence - ERROR :: [{"message":"Parameter maps cannot be used in MATCH patterns (use a literal map instead, eg. \"{id: {param}.id}\") (line 1, column 15)\n\"MATCH (p:POST {properties}) RETURN p\"\n               ^","code":"Neo.ClientError.Statement.InvalidSyntax"}] - could not execute cypher statement at location http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/75
```

So, ok, I thought. Let's go for something simpler, and I constructed my cypher like this:

```
 {"statements": [ {"statement": "MATCH (p:SOCIALNETWORK {"sn_id": "TW"} ) RETURN p"} ] }
```

But for this, the server returns that it can not deserialize the request and that it does not like the s - whichever s that is.

Here's the stack trace for it:

```
 TRACE Neo4JPersistence - sending cypher {"statements": [ {"statement": "MATCH (p:SOCIALNETWORK {"sn_id": "TW"} ) RETURN p"} ] } to endpoint http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/76
 TRACE Neo4JPersistence - GET to http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/76 returned status code 200, returned data: {"commit":"http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/76/commit","results":[],"transaction":{"expires":"Sun, 23 Nov 2014 21:18:01 +0000"},"errors":[{"code":"Neo.ClientError.Request.InvalidFormat","message":"Unable to deserialize request: Unexpected character ('s' (code 115)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries\n at [Source: org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$Input@43b86dc2{HttpChannelOverHttp@12dfe4a{r=10,a=DISPATCHED,uri=/db/data/transaction/76},HttpConnection@7291ace0{FILLING},g=HttpGenerator{s=START},p=HttpParser{s=END,87 of 87}}; line: 1, column: 59]"}]}
 ERROR Neo4JPersistence - ERROR :: [{"message":"Unable to deserialize request: Unexpected character ('s' (code 115)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries\n at [Source: org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$Input@43b86dc2{HttpChannelOverHttp@12dfe4a{r=10,a=DISPATCHED,uri=\/db\/data\/transaction\/76},HttpConnection@7291ace0{FILLING},g=HttpGenerator{s=START},p=HttpParser{s=END,87 of 87}}; line: 1, column: 59]","code":"Neo.ClientError.Request.InvalidFormat"}] - could not execute cypher statement at location http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/76
```

I'm stuck and frustrated by now. Can anyone help me again???

Thanks so much in advance,

Christian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike CREATE, MATCH cannot use a property map- it requires you to use literals. 
So your query should end up looking like this:

```
{
  "statements" : 
    [
      {
        "statement": "MATCH (p:SOCIALNETWORK {sn_id: {snid}} ) RETURN p",
        "parameters": {"snid": "TW"}
        }
    ]
}
```

In your second query, don't put the property key in quotes:

```
{"statements": 
 [
  {
    "statement": "MATCH (p:SOCIALNETWORK {sn_id: 'TW'} ) RETURN p"
  } 
 ] 
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I got it working with your answer. One question remains however. How do I get the id, or even better the url of the node I found with above query. I was hoping to receive the extensions json structure with the query, so I could use the self- field within the json. But it does not look like it's returned. Can you guide me on this as well?

Comment: Returning ID(p) will give you another column with the node ID. If you want the full URL of the node, then include resultDataContents: ["REST"] as in {"statements": [ {"statement": "MATCH (p:SOCIALNETWORK {sn_id: 'TW'} ) RETURN p", "resultDataContents" : [ "REST" ]} ] } See http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-transactional.html#rest-api-execute-statements-in-an-open-transaction-in-rest-format-for-the-return

Comment: Sorry for the typo. Meant to write that, for all folks looking to easily get the self object from this rather lengthy response, here's the code:  JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)new JSONParser().parse("your json string"); String self = (String)((JSONObject)((JSONArray)((JSONObject)((JSONArray)((JSONObject)((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results")).get(0)).get("data")).get(0)).get("rest")).get(0)).get("self");

Answer (score 0):

Since version 2.0.5, you CAN use a property map with `MATCH`<sup>¥</sup> ([and `MERGE`](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.0.5/query-merge.html#merge-using-map-parameters-with-merge)):

```
{
  "statements" : 
    [
      {
        "statement": "MATCH (p:SOCIALNETWORK {sn_id: {properties}.sn_id)} ) RETURN p",
        "parameters": { "properties": {"snid": "TW"} }
        }
    ]
}
```

Not quite yet as smooth as with `CREATE` but still an improvement.

---

<sup><sup>¥</sup> Unfortunately it's officially documented only for `MERGE` and not for `MATCH`, but tested and used everyday by yours truly</sup>